# RAZOR how to call server side url POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor

We have two webservers which are on an intranet.  Server A is mine, and server B is running Tableau.

I essentially want to do this:

```
    var myTicket =  what you would get if this ran AS the server:

                    var tableau_params = { username: 'DistrictDataReader'};
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://Dataviz:8080/trusted",
                        data: tableau_params,
                        success: function (msg) {  I want to set my myTicket to equal what comes back form server B}
                    });
```

I tried a bunch of things putting the ajax call inside of Javascript -  however I am quite sure that it is really not running from the webserver -  but rather, the  client.   I had tried two flavors of the ajax call   both giving me CORS errors.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Result").click(function () {
                var tableau_params = { username: 'DistrictDataReader'};
                var ticket;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://Dataviz:8080/trusted",
                    data: tableau_params,

                    //  First format attempt
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        ticket = $('#Result').html(msg.d);
                    }

                    //  Second format attempt
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        ticket = $('#Result').text(msg.d);
                    }

                });

                alert(ticket);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I also tried opening up CORS on server B to allow anything through ,  but given that both of the examples above return origin errors I am quite sure this is really not running form my webserver .

So I would like another way to do this.     I really just want to set my variable myTicket  from a POST to http://dataviz:8080/trusted with a parameter set { username: 'DistrictDataReader'}

How do I do this?

I am on a single cshtml page in RAZOR.

Comment: One additional(?) basic problem. You are doing an asynchronous Ajax call, which returns values much later, but are trying to alert the returned values immediately. "That is like ordering a pizza, then trying to eat it before it is delivered" :)

Answer (score 1):

figured it out:

this is how to do with no AJax:

```
@{


  string postData = "username=DistrictDataReader";
  byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
  var myTicket = "";

        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://dataviz:8080/trusted");

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

            // Write the request
            Stream outStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            outStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            outStream.Close();

            // Do the request to get the response
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader inStream = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
            string resString = inStream.ReadToEnd();
            inStream.Close();

            myTicket = resString;
        }
        catch {myTicket = "Ooops!";}

        Response.Redirect("http://dataviz:8080/trusted/"+ myTicket +"/views/SBACStateandCounty/VermontMap");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's still not allowing cross-origin, then something with your CORS setup is not correct. You haven't provided any information evaluate that though.

An alternative option is to use JSONP, assuming the external site supports it or can be made to support it. That bypasses the need for CORS entirely.

Comment: Well CORS is really kind of out -  it is set up correctly (whole other post about that) -  but the call is not coming as the server.

Comment: I really want to know is there a way in RAZOR to set a variable as follows:   var MyTicket =     get result of POST to http:_____  username = 'someaccountname'

Comment: No, not as such. I mean, given that Razor can run C# code, you can create an `HttpClient`, request something with it, parse the result and then set a variable with that result. However, something like that should really be done outside of the view.